# Passing vars from -> to functional components in React using react-router-dom (<Route>)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-functional-component

I can't seem to get my functional components to pass a variable like I expect.  I've tried passing props, didn't work, I'm also not sure if the syntax is the same with purse functional components.  Any tips?

app.js:

```
const [showRecommender, setRecommenderVisible] = React.useState(true);

 <Switch>
        <Route
          path='/'
          render={() => <LandingPage showRecommender={showRecommender} />}
          //ALSO TRIED: render={(props) => <LandingPage {...props} showRecommender={showRecommender} />}
        />
    </Switch>
```

LandingPage.js:

```
const LandingPage = ({showRecommender}) => {
console.log("showRecommender val from landingPage:", showRecommender);  //getting undefined????
```

Comment: That's weird, I use the syntax that you have commented out (with props), and it works

Comment: make sure you don't have more instances of LandingPage in your code

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri just the one listed.  *shrug*

Comment: Can you create a small demo to reproduce your issue

Comment: I feel like a bone-head.  I had the commented out code just before and it was still executing.  As soon as I removed the commented out line it worked as expected.  
<Switch>
            // <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPage}/>
            <Route
              path='/'
              render={() => <LandingPage showRecommenderVal={showRecommender} />}
            />
          </Switch>
ugh...sorry guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still had my original code 'commented' out, or so I thought...it was still executing the commented out line.  Once removed, it worked as expected... bonehead move, sorry all.

```
<Switch>
            // <Route path="/" exact component={LandingPage}/>
            <Route
              path='/'
              render={() => <LandingPage showRecommenderVal={showRecommender} />}
            />
          </Switch>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works fine. Can you please match your code with the code below and let me know if your issue is solved.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import LandingPage from "./components/LandingPage";

function App() {
  const [showRecommender, setRecommenderVisible] = React.useState(true);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route
          path="/"
          render={() => <LandingPage showRecommender={showRecommender} />}
        />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

LandingPage.js

```
import React from "react";

const LandingPage = ({ showRecommender }) => {
  console.log("showRecommender val from landingPage:", showRecommender);
  return <div>landing page</div>;
};

export default LandingPage;
```

Browser Console

```
showRecommender val from landingPage: true            LandingPage.js:4
```